# How do i turn on the Remote DNS feature of Firefox's proxy settings via Selenium(Python)?

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am writing a program which consists of a browser (Firefox) that has been set to use proxy, to go and open websites and links.

Here is a part of my source code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

def my_proxy(PROXY_HOST,PROXY_PORT):
        fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
        print PROXY_PORT
        print PROXY_HOST
        fp.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
        fp.set_preference("network.proxy.socks",PROXY_HOST)
        fp.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_port",int(PROXY_PORT))
        fp.set_preference("general.useragent.override","whatever_useragent")
        fp.update_preferences()
        return webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp
```

How do i turn on the *Remote DNS* feature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the [`network.proxy.socks_remote_dns`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.proxy.socks_remote_dns) to `True`:

```
fp.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_remote_dns", True)
```

Comment: Thank you! Where did you find out that preference?

Comment: @The_Diver basically just opened "about:config" and searched for "dns". Then the preference rechecked online.